# Can group cohomology be used to study fiber bundles?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, vector-bundles, group-cohomology

Is (non-abelian) cohomology used to study vector and principal bundles?
Can you give me a text or an article?
For example:

Consider a vector bundle $E$ with fiber $V$ and base manifold $M$. 
Consider the loop group $L$ of $M$ based at a point $p$.

The holonomy of a connection is a morphism of groups $\omega:L\to Aut(V)$, where $V$ is the fiber at $p$, that gives the parallel transport of a vector around the loop, and defines on $V$ an $L$-module structure.

Therefore we can consider an extension:
$$
0 \rightarrow V \hookrightarrow G \rightarrow L \rightarrow 1.
$$

If the sequence is split, $G=V\rtimes L$ is made of elements in the form $(v, x)$ which compose in the following way:
$$
(v,x)(w,y) = (v+xw, xy),
$$

which can be seen as composing the loops, and summing the vectors after $w$ has been transported around the loop $x$.

I would think that the sequence is a direct product if and only if the bundle is trivial, because the action of $L$ on $V$ is trivial.
Going this way, I'm also tempted to think that a connection is linked with splittings of this exact sequence.

Can anybody enlighten me?

Comment: Crossposting this to MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/160557/can-group-cohomology-be-used-to-study-fiber-bundles.